Upper and lower bounds in integral for potential
So I have problem with understanding and determining electric potential. I'm going to explain how I think through an example and where it the breaks down in another example.
Example 1 from griffiths book page 82:
Find the potential inside and outside a spherical shell of radius R
that carries a uniform surface charge. Set the reference point at infinity.
For $r>R$, $V(r)=-\int^r_\infty E\cdot dl$.
I'm thinking a test charge comes from infinity to $r>R$ and we are calculating the work needed to bring it there.
For $r<R$ we have $V(r)=-\int^R_\infty E\cdot dl -\int^r_R 0\cdot dl$.
Same thing a test charge is brought from infinity to R under the electrical field $E$ and then from $R$ to $r$ under the field 0.
Second example: Two concentric spherical metal shells have radius $a$ and $2a$. The inner shell has potential $V_o$ and the outer shell is grounded. In $r<a$, $a<r<2a$ and $r>2a$ there is vacuum. Determine the potential everywhere.
The potential when $r<a$ is $V_O$ since the electrical field is $0$ there.
According to my teacher when $a<r<2a$ the potential is given by $V(r)=V_0-\int^r_aE(r)\cdot dl$ where $E$ is the electrical field in $a<r<2a$.
Here my thought process seemingly breaks down. I would write $V(r)=-\int^{2a}_\infty E_1\cdot dl-\int^r_{2a}E_2\cdot dl$. Do I get a different answer because the reference point is different. So my reference point is infinity while the other answer has it at center of the spherical shells.
Also since the outer shell is grounded $V(2a)=0$ but how is $V(r)=0$ if $r>2a$ is there not an electrical field there.

I think the confusion might be resolved if we clarify what exactly the second sphere being 'grounded' means. It means that the conductor is connected to some "external" reservoir of charge, from which charge can freely enter or leave the conductor. Therefore the total amount of charge on the sphere will adjust itself to be in the minimum energy configuration, just like how a ball will roll down to the bottom of a hill.
If we accept this as the definition of being grounded, it becomes clear that there can be no electric field for $r > 2a$. If there were such a field, we could reduce the total energy of the system by either adding or subtracting additional charge to the grounded field, letting these extra charges flow in from (or out to) infinity.
Since there is no external field, it follows that $V(2a) = 0$, given that our reference is at infinity.
Note that $V_0$ is not a reference potential, unless you define $V_0 = 0$ (and then the grounded sphere will not be at zero potantial). Therefore, there is no contradiction. On the contrary, if you know the charge density on the inner sphere, you can determine $V_0$ from the integral $V_0 = - \int_{\infty}^{0} E \cdot dr$.

nice answer but it still needs the explanation for the claim that "the total amount of charge on the sphere will adjust itself to always be in the minimum energy configuration."

can u explain "If there were such a field, we could reduce the total energy of the system by either adding or subtracting additional charge to the grounded field, letting these extra charges flow in from (or out to) infinity."

@hyportnex Thanks for your comment, I edited the answer to clarify.

@perpersson If there was for instance a field pointing radially inward, we could reduce the total (potential) energy of the system by moving a positive charge from infinity to the outer conductor.


Example 1 from griffiths book page 82:
Same thing a test charge is brought from infinity to $R$ under the electrical field $E$ and then from $R$ to $r$ under the field $0$.

Correct.

Second example:
The potential when $r\leqslant a$ is $V_0$ since the electrical field is $0$ there.

Correct.

When $a\leqslant r\leqslant2a$ the potential is given by $V(r)=V_0−\int^r_aE(r)\cdot\mathrm d\ell$ where $E$ is the electrical field in $a\leqslant r\leqslant2a$.

Something like this is definitely correct; I am not going to check your signs.

Also since the outer shell is grounded $V(2a)=0$ but how is $V(r)=0$ if $r\geqslant2a$ is there not an electrical field there.

Yes, there is no electric field outside the grounded outer shell. That is what it means to ground that outer shell.

You should be able to produce the exact functional form of $V(r)$ for all $r\in\mathbb R^+_0$, written as piecewise functions. You should not have any leftover dependence upon the electric fields involved.
